# MS SQL GO-Command for Impala-SQL

Tags: sql, impala

I need help again. I'm struggling with Impala and want to know, if the GO-command exists also for Impala? I need to run multiple queries after each other. Google does not provide any answer and in the official documentation there is nothing stated. But I want to be sure that there is really no possibility.

For example:

```
USE [DATABASE]
GO
-- Delete Table A
DROP TABLE [dbo].[A]
GO
-- Delete Table B
DROP TABLE [dbo].[B]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running your script? What happened when you did? 

UnreIated, and most likely just me being pedantic, but I typically use the statement terminator (semi-colon `;`) as well.

Comment: `GO` is not a command in SQL Server either. It's a batch separator parsed by tools like `sqlcmd` and Management Studio, but the engine itself doesn't process it. SQL Server allows multi-statement batches even without `GO`, whereas many engines do not (especially not for DDL statements), but even SQL Server itself can't process statements that need to have a batch to their own without client support.

Comment: You just need to terminate each statement with a semi-colon (and remove the GOs)

Comment: Thank you for all your replies, but none of the suggestions works for me.

Comment: What works: Copy each query, terminate each with a semicolon and after that just mark everything with control and hit the run button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works: Copy each query, terminate each with a semicolon and after that just mark everything with control and hit the run button